# How to convert element into dictionary format using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on chatbot where I used multiple technologies. following code is working fine , I want to convert res['path'] into dictionary format so that I can display result on chatbot using javascript . how I can do it.

```
     if 'Sorry I could not understand' in xx:
        index_dir = os.path.join(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0],"textdata")
        ix= open_dir(index_dir)    
        with ix.searcher() as searcher:
            query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse(Input)
            results= searcher.search(query, limit=3)
            if len(results)!=0:
                for res in results:
                    print('filepath:', res['path'])
                return JsonResponse({"output": str(dict(res))}, status=200)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"output": "No result found"}, 
                status=200)
    else:
         return JsonResponse(xx, safe=False)


 Actual result - filepath: D:\data\car1\carfinance.pdf
 Expected result - In dictionary {filepath: D:\data\car1\carfinance.pdf}
```

Comment: `{"output": str(dict(res))}` - replace with `{"filepath": res['path']}`.

Comment: whoosh index contains data as filename, path and textdata . when I run attached code , it will return correct output but I want output in dict format as filename : D:\data\car1\carfinance.pdf

Comment: {"output": str(dict(res))} - replace with {"filepath": res['path']} it does not work